# Problems when combining css :target selector with url hash parameters for showing a modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

My javascript and css knowledge is rather limited. I think I am missing some subtleties of when and how css is applied as well as how page loading, combined with asynchronous javascript, calls works.

**This is working:**
I have a css only modal which displays when the id of my modal (`view`) matches the hash in the url (`#view`). I use it to display images (it is the same modal div for all images and the actual image src is updated via event listeners added to links to the modals' anchor). This is working fine.

**This is working:**
I wanted to extend this so I could directly link to an already open popup by providing the url as a hash parameter. I.e. `example.com/#view=imageUrl`. Just opening this will not make the css selector `:target` match, since it now contains the view, but if I split this off by checking `var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);` I can separate the url from the anchor and if I then use:

```
window.history.pushState("", "", window.location.href.split('=')[0]);
updateModal(imageUrl)
```

where `updateModal` sets the source of the image to the split off url. All is fine, too, i.e. the site opens with the modal open and the image from the url in there.

**This is not working:**
Now I thought, it is possible that the image provided as hash parameter does not exist anymore, so I only want to show the modal if there is a valid image provided, otherwise go to the main page. I created a dummy image element, try loading the image from `imageUrl` and move the splitting and updating bits to the onload method of the dummy image, like so:

```
dummyImage.onload = function () {
    window.history.pushState("", "", window.location.href.split('=')[0])
    updateModal(imageUrl)
}
```

If I do this, the modal does not show. The css does not get applied, why is this?

I also tried changing the visibility of the modal myself:

```
dummyImage.onload = function () {
    window.history.pushState("", "", window.location.href.split('=')[0])
    updateModal(imageUrl)
    var myModal = document.getElementById('view')
    myModal.style.display = 'flex'
    myModal.style.visibility = 'visible'
}
```

Which makes the modal appear, but seems to add a style that cannot be overridden by the css anymore. Specifically, when I click the close link of the modal which just goes to a different anchor `#noname` the url changes, the css `:target` selector should not match anymore, but the modal does not close anymore. Why would the css not apply anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the below links, I believe this is a bug and that, on changing the url with pushState, the :target selector is not re-evaluated after page load. I will work around this by always showing the modal, as in the second working example in the question and use a fall-back image and message to alert the users that the image is no longer available (I can trigger this update with `dummyImage.onerror`).

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83490
- https://css-tricks.com/on-target/
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/503
- https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/639

If anybody knows a better solution or workaround, I am still interested to learn!